# How to add my exe to the installed apps list in windows using python

Tags: python, installation, windows-installer

##### I wont to make an installer for my app and I want a custom one. *I don't wont to use Inno installer or something like it*

Is there An windows API, python lib or something that I can use to add my exe program to the installed apps section in the windows.
in this list HERE :
[image]

*I tried searching for a folder that windows uses to store installer app but I didn't found any.*

Comment: This is the documentation for building MSIX package https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/source-code-overview. This won't be an easy process.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3079684, https://stackoverflow.com/q/429738

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have your application listed in the "Installed Apps" section, you typically need to create a proper installer package, which involves more than just a simple GUI. It involves creating registry entries, handling uninstallation, and other tasks that are typically done by established installer creation tools like Inno Setup, WiX, or NSIS.

If you want your application to be listed in the "Installed Apps" section, you should consider using one of these established installer tools. Creating a full-fledged installer package is a complex task that goes beyond the scope of a simple Python script or GUI.
The steps to create an installation package for your app and have it listed in the section of installed apps on various platforms (such as Windows, macOS, and Linux).

1. **Prepare Your Application:**
   Ensure that your GUI application is fully developed, tested, and ready for distribution.
   Organize all the necessary files, including executable binaries, libraries, assets, and configuration files.
2. **Choose an Installer Tool:**
   Inno Setup for Windows. -
   Wix Toolset for Windows. -
   InstallShield for Windows. -
   DMG Canvas for macOS...
3. **Create Installation Scripts:**
   Write scripts or configurations to define how your application should be installed on the target system. This includes specifying installation paths, desktop shortcuts, Start menu entries, etc.
4. **Include Dependencies:**
   If your application depends on certain libraries or runtime environments, ensure they are included in the installation package or specify the prerequisites in the installer script.
5. **Create an Installer Package:**
   Use the selected installer tool to package your application and its dependencies into an installer package. This may involve creating an executable installer file, an installation package for a package manager (e.g., .deb for Debian-based Linux), or a disk image (DMG) for macOS.
6. **Testing:**
   Test the installer on different target platforms to ensure it works correctly and installs your application as expected and verify that shortcuts, icons, and menu entries are created correctly.
7. **Code Signing (Optional):**
   Consider code signing your installer and application to enhance security and trustworthiness. This is especially important on macOS and Windows.
8. **Distribution:**
   Make the installer package available for download on your website or through app stores, if applicable.
9. **Documentation:**
   Provide clear installation instructions and documentation for users.
10. **Support Updates and Uninstallation:**
    Ensure that your installer supports updating your application to newer versions and include an uninstallation option in the installer for users who want to remove your application.
11. **Compliance and Licensing:**
    Ensure that your application and installer comply with all relevant licensing agreements, copyrights, and legal requirements.

**-----BUT-----**

If you only want to have the app listed in the section of installed apps, you can use the `winreg` library to interact with the Windows Registry and add the app

```
import os
import winreg, win32com

# Define your application information
app_name = "your app name"
app_uninstall_path = os.path.abspath("uninstall.exe") # create an uninstall exe
app_icon_path = os.path.abspath("icon.ico") # Add the icon
app_exe_path = os.path.abspath("myapp.exe") 
shortcut_path = os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'], 'Microsoft', 'Windows', 'Start Menu', 'Programs')+f'\{app_name}.lnk'

# Registry key for installed applications
key = winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER
sub_key = r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\YourappID" # change the app id to whatever you want

#This function will add the app to the installed section 
def add_to_installed_apps(app_name,app_uninstall_path,app_icon_path):
    
    try:
        with winreg.CreateKey(key, sub_key) as registry_key:
            winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, "DisplayName", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, app_name)
            winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, "UninstallString", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, app_uninstall_path)
            winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, "DisplayIcon", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, app_icon_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

# This function will add the app to the start menu
def create_shortcut(app_exe_path, shortcut_path, app_icon_path=None):
    # Create a shortcut to the target
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(shortcut_path)
    shortcut.Targetpath = app_exe_path
    shortcut.IconLocation = app_icon_path
    shortcut.save()
    
create_shortcut(app_exe_path,shortcut_path,app_icon_path)
add_to_installed_apps(app_name,app_uninstall_path,app_icon_path)
```

This code will add the app that you create to the installed apps section in Windows. Please ensure that you also include an uninstaller executable to remove the files and registry entries created by the app.

Comment: can i use my own GUI and use inno setup in the background ??

Comment: While it is possible to use tkinter and subprocess to run the Inno Setup installer from Python, this approach may not be the most efficient way to handle installations. While it can work for basic installations, Inno Setup is designed to be run as a standalone tool, and using it within a Python GUI application can introduce some complexity and may not provide the same level of efficiency and control as running it directly through its native interface.